# How would I find the variance here?

Tags: variance

Say a newspaper offers an online subscription that has a $12/year edition, as well as a free version that brings in no revenue. 70% of subscribers use the free version, and 30% use the paid version. In a year, what is the variance of the revenue from one subscriber?

This question is probably very simple but I'm not sure how to approach it. Could there be a use of the binomial distribution here? And if so, how would I apply it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a random variable that takes value $12$ with probability $0.7$, and value $0$ with probability $0.3$. Find the variance of this random variable. (The computation will be very similar to how you would find the variance of a Bernoulli random variable.)

Alternate slick way: your random variable is $12$ times a certain Bernoulli random variable. How does the variance of a random variable change when you multiply it by a constant?